# Is a figure eight a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Let $S$ be image of function of $f : (-\pi,\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined $f(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t)$. Which is figure-eight. Now it is not manifold because there is self-intersection. But it is immersed submanifold of dimension 1. Which implies that it is a smooth manifold. Isn't this contradiction. where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Why is it an immersed submanifold?

Comment: what definition of "manifold" are you using?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure-eight_knot_(mathematics)) under "mathematical properties".

Comment: In my opinion the concept of an *immersed submanifold* leads to misunderstandings as in your question. See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3899905.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The figure-eight, with the standard topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$, is not a manifold because in the crossing point there is no neighborhood homeomorphic to some Euclidean space.

However the figure-eight IS a manifold with the topology induced by the immersion $f$, because in this topology there is a neighborhood of the crossing point that is homeomorphic to an open interval in the real line (the topology induced by $f$ imply that the figure-eigth is homeomorphic to $(-\pi,\pi)$).

Comment: Aaah! Thanks so much. I had this fixed idea that self-intersection => Not a manifold.  Makes sense. immersed submanifold has flexibility of what kind of topology we can impose unlike embedded submanifold. This example will make me remember that !