# Uniqueness of topology and smooth structure on an immersed submanifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am reading "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by Lee and encountered the following theorem:

If $N,M$ are smooth manifolds and $F: N \rightarrow M $ is an injective smooth immersion, then $S = F(N)$ has a unique topology and smooth structure such that $S$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$, and $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

The book defines a set $O \subseteq S$ as open if and only if $F^{-1}(O)$ is open in $N$. It defines a smooth structure on $S$ by taking chart $(U, \phi)$ on $M$ and defining a corresponding chart on $S$ as $(F(U), \phi \circ F^{-1})$.

**My question is how is the topology and smooth structure unique?**

Specifically, I can take the topology on $S$ to be the subspace topology inherited from $M$ and define the corresponding smooth structure on $S$ by taking any chart $(U, \phi)$ on $M$ and defining a corresponding chart $(U \cap S, \phi \circ F^{-1})$ on $S$. This defines a smooth structure since for any two charts $(U \cap S, \phi \circ F^{-1}),$ and $ (V \cap S, \psi \circ F^{-1})$, we have $\psi \circ F^{-1} \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}$ which is smooth, so the charts are compatible.

The inclusion map $\iota: S \rightarrow M$ is also a smooth immersion since each point $s \in S$ has chart $(U \cap S, \phi \circ F^{-1})$ and $(U, \phi)$ about $\iota(s)$,
$$
\phi \circ \iota \circ F \circ \phi^{-1} = \phi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}
$$

which is a smooth immersion. So, $S$ is an immersed submanifold.

Finally, $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image because $F$ is assumed smooth and injective, and $F^{-1}: S \rightarrow N$ "in coordinates" is $\phi \circ F^{-1} \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}$ which is smooth.

**Therefore, this topology and smooth structure satisfies the properties we sought to prove, despite the topology nor smooth structure not being the same as the intial ones proposed in the book?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of an *immersed manifold* often leads to confusion and I do not see a real benefit to use it.

Let us consider a more general situation: Given a smooth manifold $M$, a set $S$ and a bijection $f : N \to S$. Then it is clear that

1. there exists a unique topology $\tau$ on $S$ making $f :  N \to (S,\tau)$ a homeomorphism.
2. there exists a unique smooth structure $\mathfrak D$ on $(S,\tau)$ making $f :  N \to (S,\tau,\mathfrak D)$ a diffeomorphism.

Lee uses this with $S = F(N)$. His definition of open sets and of charts is nothing else than the explicit construction of $\tau$ and $\mathfrak D$.

The problem is that $\tau$ in general is **not** the subspace topology inherited from $M$. As an example take the injective smooth immersion $\beta :  N = (-\pi,\pi) \to \mathbb R^2$ decribed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067540/an-injective-immersion-that-is-not-a-topological-embedding). Its image $S$ is a "figure eight" which is compact and thus cannot be homeomorphic to $N$. Moreover $S$ is not a manifold. Thus, unfortunately, your approach does not work.

You see that the "immersed submanifold structure" of $S$ is a fairly artificial thing which has nothing to do with the subspace $S$ of $\mathbb R^2$.

Also have a look at [Restricting the codomain of a smooth map to submanifold is smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899905/restricting-the-codomain-of-a-smoot-map-to-submanifold-is-smooth./3900539#3900539).

**Update:**

Let us consider the bijective function $\bar F : N \stackrel{F}{\to} F(N)$. We endow $F(N)$ with the unique topology and smooth structure making $\bar F$ a diffeomorphism. If $\iota : F(N) \hookrightarrow M$ denotes inclusion, then clearly $\iota \circ \bar F = F$. Since $\bar F$ is a diffeomorphism, we get $\iota = F \circ \bar F^{-1}$. This shows that $\iota$ is an injective immersion because $F$ is one.

Comment: A great and thorough answer. Reviewing my post again, I've clearly failed to verify that $S$ with its topology is a manifold (which it doesn't necessarily have to be!) Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I understand, as stated by Paul Frost, that there exist a unique topology $\tau$ and a unique structure $\mathfrak D$ for $S=F(N)$ such that $F:N\rightarrow F(N)$ is a diffeomorphism. However, my question is: are the same topology $\tau$ and structure $\mathfrak D$ also the unique ones that guarantee the inclusion $\iota:F(N)\rightarrow M$ is a (smooth) injective immersion? I think that the author Lee says that, but I don't know how to prove it and haven't seen it elsewhere. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Suzane See my update.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Your update is indeed present in the book’s discussion, but I think it does not prove what I want; in other words, if the topology/structure is chosen simply to make the inclusion an injective immersion, does that necessarily imply $F:N\rightarrow F(N)$ is a diffeomorphism? That would ensure what I want.

Comment: @Suzane You should ask a new question. We cannot use comments to discuss this point.

Comment: @PaulFrost I guess one reason to use the concept immersed submanifold is Lie group theory.